# Apollo cache fails when query variables change

Tags: react-apollo, apollo-client, apollo-cache-inmemory

I'm using useLazyQuery() to get analytic data measured by a time filter. When the time filter change, the cache returns the same values despite the filter.

I'm using the default fetchPolicy (cache-first).

```
const [
    getVisitorsAnalytics,
    { loading, data },
] = useAnalyticVisitorsLazyQuery()

const handleTimeFilterChange = (timeFilter: string) => {
    getVisitorsAnalytics({
      variables: {
        input: {
          timeFilter,
        },
      },
    })
}
```

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 0):

I think the values are cached and the cache doesn't have the data for the new filter value passed -

```
const { data, loading } = useLazyQuery(QUERY, {
        fetchPolicy: 'network-only'
    });
```